# Graph visualisation software with easy navigation capabilities

Tags: data-visualization, graphs

Graph visualisation software with easy navigation capabilities

Is there a user-end software and/or a coding library/framework in PHP that allows one to load a mathematical graph (as defined by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) and allows one to:
(1) Find all sinks and sources quickly
(2) Isolate one walk/path/trail between two specified nodes
(3) MOST IMPORTANTLY: With arrow keys on the keyboard, navigate between adjacent nodes. Up arrow - for the parent of the node. Down arrow - for the child of the node. Left and right arrows - for the siblings of the node
(4) For coloured graphs, allow the enabling and disabling of nodes and edges of a specified colour. eg. With a graph of pink and blue, allow the disabling and enabling of blue edges and nodes.

Need it for use on macOS10.13.6, and preferably open source, or at least free.
User-end software is the most preferred, followed by coding library in PHP. Other programming languages also possible, if PHP is not possible. eg. Javascript

Comment: erm, may I know why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript there is [VisJS-Network](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/).
It was a commercial software, then the Dutch parent company open-sourced it, abandoned it; then a OSS community took over, and rewrote it .

Therefore there is a new version and a legacy version, this makes looking for examples elsewhere a bit confusing.

There is an "Interaction" module for keyboard events. On the [examples page](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/) I don't see an example that implements navigating between nodes with keyboard, only [dragging the canvas](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/navigation.html).
Maybe someone else has programmed what you intended.